# Why Zariski topology is not Hausdorff

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I am reading the book about Algebraic geometry. I am confused about the following 
two things the book mentioned:

Zariski topology is

**1. different from the topology studied in real and complex analysis.

2. not Hausdorff.**

Well, I roughly now about Hausdorff and some def. in real and complex analysis. However,
I cannot know why still.

A hint or direction for thinking is ok.

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Zariski topology on $K$, where $K$ is a finite field, **is** indeed Hausdorff. However, as soon as $K$ is infinite, it is not Hausdorff. This might be interesting, if you are reading a book on algebraic geometry. 
The Zariski topology is the coarsest topology which satisfies the $T_1$ separation axiom, which means that singleton sets are closed.

So let $K$ be an infinite field. Then The Zariski topology over $K$ is not Hausdorff. Indeed, if we have any two nonempty open sets
$U$ and $V$ , then $U^c$ and $V^c$ are finite, so $(U \cap V )^c = U^c \cup V^c$ is finite as well. In particular, $U \cap V$ is nonempty. Thus, open neighborhoods of any two points $x$ and $y$ will intersect.

Comment: May I ask why Zarisky topology is $T_1$?  Are there any conditions assumed here? A simple counterexample is the Zarisky topology of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @BingyanLiu $K=\Bbb Z$ is not a field.

Comment: this answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918669/when-is-the-zariski-topology-t-2, fixes the argument for when we are dealing with $K^n$  with $n>1$.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** What are the Zariski open subsets of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: If its complement is Zariski closed. But in general case the complement of an open set is closed.

Comment: That's true for any topology. The question is more the following: What are the open sets in *this particular* topology?