# Infinite intersection of prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $p_{i}, i\in I$ and $p$ be prime ideals in $A$, where the index set $I$ is infinite. If we have
$$
p\supset \bigcap_{I}p_{i}
$$
Do we still have $p\supset p_{i}$ for some $i\in I$ like the finite index case? In the finite case, assume contrary we pick up elements $x_{i}\in p_{i}\cap p^{c}$ we would have $\prod_{i\in I'}p_{i}\in \bigcap_{I'}p_{i}\in p$, and the proof is immediate. But it is not clear to me what happens in the above case. I now suspect it would not hold in general, but I do not have a quick 5-line proof of this or an enlightening counter-example to myself. Since this is simple, I do not know if this is really up to research level. I did googled around and checked some references, but it seems it is not covered anywhere. The obvious case is when $\bigcap p_{i}=0$ (as pointed out by Qiaochu). I am wondering if there is any other non-trivial cases.

It is not very clear to me how to show if $\bigcap p_{i}=0$, then the closure of the set $p_{i}$ is the whole space $Spec A$. So even in this case I have some trouble.

Motivation: This showed up in a step when I [attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097239/closure-and-neighborhoods-in-speca/1097349#1097349) to show $V(I(S))\subset \overline{S}$ when $S$ has infinite cardinality. Perhaps my approach was not right and this is simply wrong in general.

Answer (score 5):

No. Take, for example, $A = \mathbb{Z}, p_i$ the prime ideals generated by the primes greater than $3$, and $p = (2)$.

Comment: I see where you get this. I suppose with some modification I can get the case $\bigcap_{i\in I}p_{i}\not=\langle 0\rangle$. Thanks.

Comment: @Bombyxmori If you really want an example where $\cap P_i\ne(0)$, then move all these in $\mathbb Z[X]$ by considering $P_i=(p_i,X)$.

Comment: @YACP: Yes, I think this is a good example. What I am really looking for is some way to prove $V(I(O))=\overline{O}$ in this case, since my method obviously does not work for infinite intersections even when the intersection is $\langle 0\rangle$. I suppose this should be something elementary and I just got stuck on it.