# When is there a one to one correspondence between closed sets in the Zariski topology of the prime spectrum of a ring and radical ideals of that ring?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, zariski-topology

### My current understanding: this is always true

Let $A$ be a ring. Let $S$ denote a subset of the ring. Let $V(S)$ be the set of prime ideals of $A$ containing $S$. Define closed sets in $X= \operatorname{Spec} (A)$ to be those of the form $V(S)$.

As I understand, to any radical ideal $I$, we can uniquely associated the closed set $V(I)$. Conversely, to any closed set $V$, we can associate the radical ideal given by the intersection of all elements of $V$.

I can provide proofs I have written to these if this helps, I haven't added them now to avoid drowning my question.

### My worry

I haven't been able to find anything on closed sets - radical ideal correspondence, except when we are specifically with algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^n_K$ and radical ideals in $K[X_1, ..., X_n]$, such as on [this page](https://everything2.com/title/the+correspondence+between+closed+sets+for+the+Zariski+topology+and+radical+ideals+in+the+polynomial+ring) linked in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097239/closure-and-neighborhoods-in-speca). I understand this is a fundamental result in algebraic geometry (which I am only just beginning to study), but I fail to see why the result may not be more general.

### My question

Is my current understanding correct, or have I made a mistake such as forgetting a fringe case ?

Comment: One small formatting tip: `$\operatorname{Spec}$` produces $\operatorname{Spec}$ and spaces correctly. I've made the upgrade for you this time.

Comment: Thank you, I'll remember next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, there is a bijective correspondence between closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and radical ideals $I\subsetneq A$ and this always holds.

This correspondence gets discussed a lot in "classical" algebraic geometry (the typical/original formulation of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, for instance) because "classical" algebraic geometry can't distinguish between all the different ideals which have the same set of zeroes - $V(x^2)=V(x)$ as affine varieties in $\Bbb A^n$ to any algebraic geometer in the 1800s, for instance. Part of the importance of upgrading to schemes is that now algebraic geometry can distinguish $V(x^2)$ and $V(x)$ because they have different *subscheme structures*, and that's usually information we keep track of. So it's slightly less important to talk about the underlying closed set.

That doesn't mean we completely forget about that, though - for any closed subset $Y$ in any scheme $X$, there is a unique way to turn this in to a closed subscheme called the *reduced induced subscheme structure*. Affine-locally this corresponds to exactly what you're talking about here - given a closed subset which can be written as the set of points underlying $V(I)\subset \operatorname{Spec} A$, consider it as the subscheme $V(\sqrt{I})$.